# Reducing the Lambda expression to a single line

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm new to Java 8 and need help to analyze if the BiFunction implementation using lambda can be reduced to a single line of code.

I'm receiving a JSON response from a REST API in the form of a String, which I want to store in a Hashmap using Gson and then my function should return the value given the Key.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
BiFunction<String,String,String> getValueFromResponseWithKey = (s1,s2)-> {
            Map<String,String> str =gson.fromJson(response,map.getClass());
            return str.get(s2);};
System.out.println(getValueFromResponseWithKey.apply(response,"accountNumber"));
```

It would be great if I could find a single line implementation of the `getValueFromResponseWithKey` function.

Comment: It seems to be you're complicating a simple map creation and get as: `Map<String, String> str = gson.fromJson(response, Map.class);
        System.out.println(str.get("accountNumber"));`

Comment: Makes sense , Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like below. You may want to add simple casting like this-

```
BiFunction<String,String,String> getValueFromResponseWithKey = 
        (s1,s2) -> ((Map<String, String>) gson.fromJson(response,map.getClass())).get(s2);
```

Comment: @Raj : I've edited the *format* of your answer. If you intended it to be in the other format, do rollback the change.